# Why do i get a wrong value for `i` integer?

Tags: c++, integer, literals, integer-overflow

Below I have simple C++ code to generate numbers with a length of 18. When I call the `gen_nums` function, `i` is equal to `1569325055` as if the number that I assign to the `i` variable was too big for it.

```cpp
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void gen_nums(){
    int i = 99999999999999999; 
    cout << i <<endl; 
}

int main()
{
   gen_nums();
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Does the compiler say anything about this code when you turn on warnings?

Comment: Datatypes on a particular architecture have a particular size. The C++ standard makes guarantees about the minimum size of certain types, but not the maximum size. That said, on most modern desktop systems (e.g. not embedded) an integer is 4 bytes. https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/types

Comment: Please read the answers to [Why should I not #include <bits/stdc++.h>?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31816095/5910058) and [Why is "using namespace std;" considered bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1452721/5910058) at some point.

Comment: If you `#include <limits>` at the top of your code, you can write `std::cout << "Maximum integer size: " << std::numeric_limits<int>::max() << std::endl;` in `main` to see the largest value an integer can hold on your system. https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/numeric_limits

Comment: *"as if the number that I assign to the `i` variable was too big for it."* -- looks like you already know what's going on. Do you have some reason to doubt your conclusion?

Comment: @JohnFilleau • I should not have mentioned it, I can't talk about it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It may be because you're assigning a value to int that is outside of its range.

When you assign an int outside its range, the behavior is implementation defined.

Some compilers truncate the higher bits to the width of the integer type you are assigning it to.

If you really want to use such large numbers, maybe use a `long long` which has a larger range.

```
void gen_nums(){
    long long i = 99999999999999999 ; 
    cout << i <<endl; 

    //for (i = 99999999999999999; i < 999999999999999999 ; i++  ){ 
    //    cout << i  << endl; 
      
        
   // }
}
```

or for convenience, you could just use auto

```
void gen_nums(){
    auto i = 99999999999999999 ; 
    cout << i <<endl; 

    //for (i = 99999999999999999; i < 999999999999999999 ; i++  ){ 
    //    cout << i  << endl; 
      
        
   // }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`99999999999999999` is outside the range of values a `int` can hold.

Answer (score 1):

Such arbitrary big values can't be held in a 4-bytes integer datatype (if you're using a 64-bit machine). Yet if you're not sure which type is appropriate to fit in it, take the help of `auto`:

```
#include <iostream>

void getNums() {
  // 'long int' after type deduction
  auto i = 99999999999999999;
  std::cout << i << std::endl;
}

int main(void) {
  getNums();

  return 0;
}
```

In my case, the `i` is deducted into a type of `long`. It may differ on your system since the architecture may differ.

On the other hand, in case you want to do-it-yourself and see the largest number a 4-bytes (i.e. 32-bits) integer could hold, you could use `limits`:

```
void getNums() {
  // 4-bytes integer on 64-bit machine
  // expands to 2,147,483,647 in my 64-bit system
  auto i = std::numeric_limits<int>::max();

  std::cout << i << std::endl;
}
```

Lastly, consider enabling the compiler warnings. This'll help you a lot.

---

<sup>Referring to a [Data Type Ranges](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/data-type-ranges?view=vs-2019) if you want to understand better.</sup>

Answer (score 0):

The max size of most integers is +2147483647. The number you give to it is too big, you should use "unsigned long long" for example. This is a page with the lengths of data types in c++. It is in German but I hope this is not a problem.
http://www.mrknowing.com/2013/10/08/datentypen-in-c-wertebereich-und-speichergroesse/

Comment: What do you mean by the "size of most integers"?

Comment: There are infinitely many integers, and most of them are larger than 2147483647 in magnitude. Change that to something like “A common limit on the maximum value of `int` in C++ implementations is 2147483647.”

Comment: Here's a good reference for the largest number: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4J9MRYJz9-4

Comment: Could you at least link to a website which is in English?

Answer (score -1):

You need to change the integer format you use, `int`, that in yours as well as in all other implementations has maximum value lower than `99999999999999999`,  into the `long long` format, which, as I read, can assume, in some implementations, maximum value of `9,223,372,036,854,775,807`.

The value you get of `int(99999999999999999) = 1569325055` is the wrong output of internal overflow.

Comment: Where does `1569325055` come from? It should be `2147483647`.

Comment: The OP stated that number is what he gets as output using `int`.

Comment: It doesn't mean that's the max value. If I do something like `int x = 4294967295; std::cout << x << '\n';` I get `-1`, which is surely not the max value.

Comment: In your case, you would have to write `unsigned int x = 4294967295;` to make it work.

Comment: I know, that's not the point. That was an example showing that OP's code doesn't necessarily print the max value of `int`.

Comment: Yes, output number would have come out negative if it were in overflow, my bad.


Apparently, `1569325055` comes out of typing `long(99999999999999999)`, that is, 17 nines.

Comment: Probably this is due to some kind of 2's complement representation quirk. This particular case I find used in C++ exercises, so I am wondering whether the OP is just testing users knowledge here. He shares your same nationality, oddly enough.

Answer (score -1):

The data type "**int**" cannot hold that range of value.

**Please try this code: using "long int" data type**

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;


void gen_nums(){
    long int i = 99999999999999999 ; 
    cout << i <<endl; 

    //for (i = 99999999999999999; i < 999999999999999999 ; i++  ){ 
    //    cout << i  << endl; 
      
        
   // }
}


int main()
{
   gen_nums();
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: There are not already enough answers? What does this answer add that the other answers do not?

Comment: This doesn't work on MinGW (probably also MSVC), where `long` is 4 bytes large. Using `long long` or `int64_t` is safer.

Answer (score -2):

You should use int64 instead of int as the number given is outside int range

- _int8 nSmall;      // Declares 8-bit integer
- _int16 nMedium;    // Declares 16-bit integer
- _int32 nLarge;     // Declares 32-bit integer
- _int64 nHuge;      // Declares 64-bit integer

Comment: "You should use int32 instead of int..." - Absolutely *not*. You should *not* use some platform specific types/typedefs when there are perfectly fine [Fixed width integer types](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/integer) (like `int64_t`) in the standard that will work across different implementations.

Answer (score -2):

The reason for that error is the range of integer in C++ is -2147483648 to 2147483647. So the largest number that you can use is 2147483647.

Comment: The range of `int` in C++ is at least `-32768` to `+32767`, and commonly the numbers you stated. Many embedded architectures still use a 16 bit integer.

Comment: The range that you stated above is the range of short int(Typical bit width 2 bytes). The range of integer is -2147483648 to 2147483647(Typical bit width 4 bytes)

Comment: @Abhijith11151: The C++ standard allows variation in the size and range of the integer types. It is incorrect to assert without qualification that the range for `int` is −2147483648 to 2147483647. Do not teach this wrong information to students. And, when writing about the `int` type, call it `int`, not “integer.”

Comment: @Abhi a modern example architecture where `int` is still 16 bits is on AVR microcontrollers. These are used in Arduinos, so have a high likelihood of being encountered by beginners. Teaching that `int` is always 32 bits will lead to extreme confusion for these people. It's more precise to say that `int` is commonly 32 bits in modern architectures, but sometimes 16 bits. The standard only guarantees that it is at least 16 bits.